# Are the latest mobile devices sensors precise enough to get a location in 3D space?

Tags: android, iphone, android-sensors

Before getting myself into code, I'm trying to find if what I want to do is even possible.

Could the sensors of an iPhone or Android device be precise enough to be able to get the location of the device relatively to a reference point?
For instance, the user activates the sensors of his device at point X, moves his phone around and the phone could still detect its location relatively to the point X?

Comment: While a good question, this is really just not suitable for this software QA site.  You're thinking of the gyros and accelerometers, not the GPS. The simple answer is "really, no".  Try it, or try a "Leap" device and see what you think.

Comment: Nope - The reason why Google needs extra sensors i.e. Project Tango https://www.google.com/atap/project-tango/